# psutil virtual memory units of measurement?

Tags: python, virtual-memory

When running psutil.virtual_memory() i'm getting output like this:

```
    >>psutil.virtual_memory()
    vmem(total=8374149120L, available=1247768576L)
```

But what unit of measurement are these values? The documentation simply claims that its the *"total physical memory available"* but nothing more. I'm trying to translate it into values that the user can actually relate to (ie GBs).

Thanks in advance

Comment: The unit of measurement is bytes. I had to scroll down to find the answer.

Answer (score 28):

why not use bit shift operator:
if you want to display in human readable way, just like this!

`values = psutil.virtual_memory()`

**display in MB format**

```
total = values.total >> 20
```

**display in GB format**

```
total = values.total >> 30
```

Comment: Smart, but it comes with a rounding error:

>>> psutil.virtual_memory().total =>
16678162432

>>> psutil.virtual_memory().total >> 20 =>
15905

>>> psutil.virtual_memory().total / (1024.0 ** 2) =>
15905.53515625

Answer (score 16):

1024^3 = Byte to Gigabyte
So I think this work:

```
import psutil
memory = psutil.virtual_memory().total / (1024.0 ** 3)
print(memory)
```

Comment: Please care to explain your post/answer.

Comment: Done @Shashanth :)

Comment: In Python, it's probably better to use `(1024.0 ** 3)` instead of `(1024^3)`

Answer (score 12):

It is in **Bytes**. To convert to a more readable format, simply use `bytes2human`

```
import psutil
from psutil._common import bytes2human

mem_usage = psutil.virtual_memory()
total_in_human_format = bytes2human(mem_usage[0])
print(total_in_human_format)
```

Output:

```
15.6G
```

Answer (score 10):

The unit of measurement specified is bytes . You can use this code to convert it into Gb's
When u use the value it will have a trailing "L" , but that doesn't affect the calculations.

```
values=psutil.virtual_memory()
def get_human_readable_size(self,num):
    exp_str = [ (0, 'B'), (10, 'KB'),(20, 'MB'),(30, 'GB'),(40, 'TB'), (50, 'PB'),]               
    i = 0
    while i+1 < len(exp_str) and num >= (2 ** exp_str[i+1][0]):
        i += 1
        rounded_val = round(float(num) / 2 ** exp_str[i][0], 2)
    return '%s %s' % (int(rounded_val), exp_str[i][1])
total_size = get_human_readable_size(values.total)
```

Comment: I think if num < 1KB (so the returned string is in bytes), then rounded_val is not initialized.  So one may need to add `    rounded_val = num` after i=0?

Answer (score 0):

Cant comment so I'm using "answer".

```
regarding "1024^3 = Byte to Gigabyte"
```

This is incorrect. The prefix Giga means 10^9. Therefore, a Gigabyte is 1000^3 Bytes. You can forget the extra 24.

Therefore: 1000^3 = Byte to Gigabyte

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't just forget that the whole industry used 1024 as a multiplier for six decades just because "Giga means x1000 in SI standard".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a 3rd party dependency, and you want to avoid magic numbers in your code, try `pint`.

This lets you work with units symbolically, and you can convert to whatever you want and get the "magnitude" at the end of your computation.

I like this because the code "self-documents" that the info from `psutil` is in bytes and then self-documents that we are converting to gigabytes.

```py
            import psutil
            import pint
            reg = pint.UnitRegistry()
            vmem_info = psutil.virtual_memory()
            total_gb = (vmem_info.total * reg.byte).to(reg.gigabyte).m
            avail_gb = (vmem_info.available * reg.byte).to(reg.gigabyte).m
            print('total_gb = {!r}'.format(total_gb))
            print('avail_gb = {!r}'.format(avail_gb))
```